# Setting element of array from Twig

Tags: php, twig

How can I set member of an already existing array from Twig?

I tried doing it next way:

```
{% set arr['element'] = 'value' %}
```

but I got the following error:

> Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "[" ("end of statement block"
>   expected) in ...

Answer (score 255, accepted):

There is no nice way to do this in Twig. It is, however, possible by using the merge filter:

```
{% set arr = arr|merge({'element': 'value'}) %}
```

If `element` is a variable, surround it with brackets:

```
{% set arr = arr|merge({(element): 'value'}) %}
```

Comment: "."-statement is the same as "[]" so it's not the solution

Comment: @falinsky You're right. `.` and `[]` are very similar in Twig and I was wrong. I looked it up and edited my answer.

Comment: I was looking for a way to define dynamic variable key in replacement of `'element'`. I found @LivaX's answer below. So, it would be `{% set arr = arr|merge({(key): 'value'}) %}`.

Comment: This is so silly. Why doesn't twig allow the ability to set array values?

Comment: @MattCavanagh because view files (such as Twig) aren't supposed to contain business logic, this should ultimately be handled in the model. The view is really supposed to simply render what's there. The issue though in my case, and why I also agree with you, is that I create twig macros to render UI objects, eg. `{{ UI.button({'type':'submit'}) }}` and all these macros use |merge for setting default params, so there is a logical need for this...

Comment: what about if we want to store numbers in values and increment that value when loop continues based on key?

Comment: @AhmedAli Depends on your exact situation, but something like this should work: `{% set arr = arr|merge({'key': arr['key'] + 1}) %}`

Comment: @Paul i want key to be my own index like a unique numeric index, can it work?

Comment: @AhmedAli Yes, you will want to use something like `{ (loop.index0): arr[loop.index0] + 1}`

Comment: Notice: if you use numeric keys (like in my case i needed key from 1 to 30), keys will be forced to be 0 based.

Comment: This solution works for creating **twig array keys dynamically**.

Answer (score 84):

I ran into this problem but was trying to create integer indexes instead of associative index like 'element'.

You need to protect your index key with `()` using the merge filter as well:

```
{% set arr = arr|merge({ (loop.index0): 'value'}) %}
```

You can now add custom index key like `('element'~loop.index0)`

Comment: That is the actual solution when you try to insert keys dynamically, thanks LivaX!

Answer (score 15):

If initialization only need:

```
{% set items = { 'apple': 'fruit', 'orange': 'fruit', 'peugeot': 'unknown' } %}
```

Comment: This was not the question.

Answer (score 5):

I have tried @LivaX 's answer but it does not work , merging an array where keys are numeric wont work ( https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/789 ).

That will work only when keys are strings

What I did is recreate another array ( `temp`) from the initial array (`t`)  and make the keys a string , for example :

```
{% for key , value in t%}
{% set temp= temp|merge({(key~'_'):value}) %}
{% endfor %}
```

`t` keys : 0 , 1 , 2 ..

`temp` keys : 0_, 1_ , 2_ ....

Comment: Same issue, no solution so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following syntax:

```
{% set myArray = myArray + myArray2 %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this like `{% set arr={'key':'value'} %}` (with no blank space after the `:`), it works well.

But when I use it inside a for loop, to make it an array, it does not work outside of the for scope.

```
{% for group in user.groups %}
  {% set foo={'loop.index0':'group.id'} %}
  {% set title={'loop.index0':'group.title'} %}
  {{ title }} //it work 
{% else %}
  {% set foo={'0':'-1'} %}
  {% set title={'0':'未分组'} %}
{% endfor %}
{{ title }}  //it does not work, saying title is not defined
```

Comment: If you want to use the variable outside of the for loop you need to define it outside of the for loop, see here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html

Comment: This is all kinds of wrong. The space after the colon does not matter. You are creating new arrays, not setting an element in the array which was the question. You can't output an array like {{ array }}, that would generate an error. This answer is full of fail and unrelated to the question asked.

Comment: I don't understand why this has upvotes, like stated above, almost everything is incorrect in this "answer"...

Answer (score 2):

```
{% set links = {} %}

{# Use our array to wrap up our links. #}
{% for item in items %}
  {% set links = links|merge({ (loop.index0) : {'url': item.content['#url'].getUri(), 'text': item.content['#title']} }) %}
{% endfor %}

{%
set linkList = {
  'title': label,
  'links': links
}
%}

{% include '<to twig file>/link-list.twig'%}
```

Thanks for this thread -- I was also able to create an array with (loop.index0) and send to twig.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this issue very annoying, and my solution is perhaps orthodox and not inline with the Twig philosophy, but I developed the following:

```
$function = new Twig_Function('set_element', function ($data, $key, $value) {
    // Assign value to $data[$key]
    if (!is_array($data)) {
        return $data;
    }
    $data[$key] = $value;
    return $data;
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

that can be used as follows:

{% set arr = set_element(arr, 'element', 'value') %}

Answer (score 2):

Adding my answer in case anyone needs to update the array when `merge` doesn't work because it just appends to the end of an array instead of providing the ability to change an existing value.

Let's say you have an array `words_array` like below:

```
Object {
 0: "First word"
 1: "Second word"
 2: "Third word"
}
```

In order to update `"Second word"`, you can do the following:

```
{% set words_array = {(1): 'New word'} + words_array %}
```

The resulting array would be:

```
Object {
 0: "First word"
 1: "New word"
 2: "Third word"
}
```

You can take it one step further if you are using a loop and use the `loop.index0` variable something like the following:

```
{% for word in words_array %}
  {% if word == 'Second word' %}
    {% set words_array = {(loop.index0): 'New word'} + words_array %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a multi dimension array. The only solution I could find out is create a new temporary array and **update/add** the information, which was further passed on to another twig function.

Comment: can u give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem sometime ago. Imagine you have an array like this one:

```
data = {
    'user': 'admin',
    'password': 'admin1234',
    'role': 'admin',
    'group': 'root',
    'profile': 'admin',
    'control': 'all',
    'level': 1,
    'session': '#DFSFASADASD02',
    'pre_oa': 'PRE-OA',
    'hepa_oa': 'HEPA-OA',
    'pre_ra': 'HEPA-RA',
    'hepa_ra': 'HEPA-RA',
    'deodor_ra': 'DEODOR-RA'
}
```

So, you want to show this data in two rows, but remove the password from that list. To this end, split in 2 arrays will be easy with the `slice` filter. However, we have to remove the password. For that reason, I'm using this snippet. The idea is to put all the elements lesser than the `data` elements size divided by 2. To calculate this we use the filter `length`. Now to get the index of the current element we user `loop.index`. And finally we *push an associative element in the left or right array. An associative array has two components `key` and `value`. To reference an array key in twit we operator `()` and we use the `merge` filter to push into the array as shown here `{% set left_list = left_list|merge({ (key): value }) %}`

This is the complete solution.

```
{% set left_list = {} %}
{% set right_list = {} %}
{% set limit = data|length // 2 %}
{% for key, value in data|cast_to_array %}
{% if key != 'password' %}
{% if loop.index <= limit %}
{% set left_list = left_list|merge({ (key): value }) %}
{% else %}
{% set right_list = right_list|merge({ (key): value }) %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for key, value in left_list %}
<p>
<label for="{{key}}">{{key}}</label>
<input type="text" name="{{key}}" id="{{key}}" value="{{value}}"
       class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can declare the array as follows

```
{% set arr = [{'element1': 'value1','element2' : 'value2'},{'element1': 'value1','element2' : 'value2'},{'element1': 'value1','element2' : 'value2'}] %}
```