# Twig: Append to array inside array/object

Tags: arrays, symfony, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I have an object which, in JSON, would look like this:

```
{
  'class': ['nav-link', 'dropdown-toggle'],
  'data-toggle': ['dropdown']
}
```

I need to then be able to append another class to the class array inside the object.

This code doesn't seem to work; it just overwrites the class array.

```
{% set link_attribs = { 'class' : ['nav-link', 'dropdown-toggle'], 'data-toggle':'dropdown'} %}
{% set link_attribs = link_attribs|merge({'class': ['highlighted']}) %}
```

Really I want to do something like this, but it  just throws a punctuation error.

```
{% set link_attribs.class = link_attribs.class|merge(['highlighted']) %}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting element of array from Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432534/setting-element-of-array-from-twig)

Answer (score 5):

Using Twig, you can't set object properties directly, so "`set (...).class`" will never work. But instead, you can create a new variable that will inherit from both `default` and `options` values (just like in most JavaScript codes).

For example:

```
{%
  set options = link_attribs | merge({
      'class': link_attribs.class | merge(['highlighted']) 
  })
%}

{% for class in options.class %}
  {{ class }}
{% endfor %}
```

Will display:

```
nav-link
dropdown-toggle
highlighted
```

See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/c00mlc).

Comment: That looks like a bit like an inline version of my possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34229624/224707. It's a shame Twig doesn't like you set object properties.

Comment: I understand your point, and in small projects this could be very useful. But changing object values in Twig doesn't make sense: as a template engine, it should only render things, without changing the application state.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it works:

```
{% set c = link_attribs.class %}
{% set c = c|merge(['highlighted']) %}
{% set link_attribs = link_attribs|merge({'class': c}) %}
```

Not sure if its the most elegant way though.