# How to count variables of array?

Tags: arrays, twig

I hava a Twig question. I have an array:

```
{% set frequency = [ 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5 ] %}
```

And `shot.punctation` is displaying: `5 6 9 3 5 6 4 2 6 5 6 3 2 4 2 8 3 2 1 4 7 5 5 6 10 9 2 7 8 6 2 3 4 1 3 8 9 7 3 4`.
And I want do something like that:

```
{% for shot in shots %}
    {% set frequency[shot.punctation] = frequency[shot.punctation] + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

but I don't know how.

I need to count every variable of my array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting element of array from Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432534/setting-element-of-array-from-twig)

Comment: I think you look for `loop.index0`?